# What are different options for objective functions available in xgboost.XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

Apart from `binary:logistic` (which is the default objective function), is there any other built-in objective function that can be used in [`xbgoost.XGBClassifier`](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's true that **binary:logistic** is the default objective for XGBClassifier, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't use other objectives offered by [XGBoost package](http://xgboost-clone.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters).
For example, you can see in *sklearn.py* source code that **multi:softprob** is used explicitly in multiclass case.

Moreover, if it's really necessary, you can provide a custom objective function (details [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn)).

Comment: what is the binary:logistic, isn't this just the loss function?

Comment: The question was "is there any built-in objective function other than b:l", and this answer says "you can use functions other than b:l". Why on earth was this selected as the right answer?

Answer (score 5):

The default objective for XGBClassifier is ['reg:linear]
however there are other parameters as well..
binary:logistic-It returns predicted probabilities for predicted class
multi:softmax - Returns hard class for multiclass classification
multi:softprob - It Returns probabilities for multiclass classification

Note: when using multi:softmax as objective, you need to pass num_class also
as num_class is number of parameters defining number of class
such as for labelliing (0,1,2), here we have 3 classes, so num_class = 3

Answer (score 2):

These are the bulit-in functions available

- Objective candidate: survival:aft
- Objective candidate: binary:hinge
- Objective candidate: multi:softmax
- Objective candidate: multi:softprob
- Objective candidate: rank:pairwise
- Objective candidate: rank:ndcg
- Objective candidate: rank:map
- Objective candidate: reg:squarederror
- Objective candidate: reg:squaredlogerror
- Objective candidate: reg:logistic
- Objective candidate: binary:logistic
- Objective candidate: binary:logitraw
- Objective candidate: reg:linear
- Objective candidate: reg:pseudohubererror
- Objective candidate: count:poisson
- Objective candidate: survival:cox
- Objective candidate: reg:gamma
- Objective candidate: reg:tweedie
- Objective candidate: reg:absoluteerror

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).